# Where did this "static" lifetime came from？

Tags: rust, lifetime

[The following program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0f313bbee1be54e8843fc6891da50b55&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) doesn't compile:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Foo<'a> {
    fn to_box_any(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<Any + 'a>;
}

fn test<'a>(v: Box<dyn Foo<'a> + 'a>) {
    v.to_box_any();
}

fn main() {}
```

Error message:

```
error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:7
  |
8 |     v.to_box_any();
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 7:1
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | fn test<'a>(v: Box<dyn Foo<'a> + 'a>) {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime
```

I thought I marked as many explicit lifetimes as I can, but I don't know where the `static` lifetime requirement came from.

If I change `Any` with a custom trait, it works, so it looks like `Any` is creating the requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the documentation for code you are trying to use. For example, the documentation for [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) says (emphasis mine)

> A type to emulate dynamic typing.
>
> Most types implement `Any`. However, **any type which contains a non-`'static` reference** does not. See the [module-level documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) for more details.

The trait itself requires a `'static` bound:

```
pub trait Any: 'static {
    fn get_type_id(&self) -> TypeId;
}
```

You can also see all the method implementations require `'static`:

```
impl Any + 'static {}
impl Any + 'static + Send {}
impl Any + 'static + Sync + Send {}
```

Comment: @trentcl good point (I hate how newer Rustdoc collapses a lot more things by default).